# Import CSV using UTF-8

Tags: excel, vba, csv, utf-8

I'm using the following Macro (thanks to The_Barman for the code!) to import a CSV-file into a worksheet called Tickets. The problem is that there are some special character like Ü,Ä, etc. in it, so I would need to import the file in the UTF-8 format. Can anybody tell me how to add this to this code?

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub CSV_Import()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String


Worksheets("Tickets").Range("A1:Z9999").Clear

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets")

strFile = "C:\test\testfile.csv"

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0

Answer (score 15):

I added ".TextFilePlatform = 65001" to the code and it's working now:

```
Sub CSV_Import()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String


Worksheets("Tickets").Range("A1:Z9999").Clear

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets")

strFile = "C:\test\testfile.csv"

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFilePlatform = 65001
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to put 65000.